# NSRegularExpression to capture portions of invalid JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have the following string that I'm trying to perform a regex string extraction on: `{"code":5,"id":104,"message":"Not working"}`. I need to perform an extraction as sometimes multiple strings can come bundled together like so: `{.....}{...}{......}`

I'm already using JSONSerialization for the cases when individual messages come in like this: `{"code":5,"id":104,"message":"Not working"}`.

I need the regex to extract the individual strings when I get get the messages like this: `{"code":5,"id":104,"message":"Not working"}{"code":5,"id":101,"message":"some message"}{"code":5,"id":105,"message":"test"}`.

I have the following regex that matches the string: `{.*?"id":104.*?}`

```objc
NSError  *error  = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"{.*?\"id\":104.*?}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
//regex is returning (null) here

NSRange range  = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:msg options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [msg length])];

NSString *result = [msg substringWithRange:range];
//Result is empty

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:msg options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [msg length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *regexStr = [msg substringWithRange:range];
}];
```

I believe the problem is with my regex. I might not be escaping it correctly.

I have tried `{.*?\\\"id\\\":104.*?}` but the result is the same.

Am I right in saying that I'd need a regex to manage and extract the strings when multiple arrive in?

Comment: I think its a kind of JOSN formate why don't you use JSONSerilation for this ?

Comment: is this `{"code":5,"id":104,"message":"Not working"}` string  or dictioanry

Comment: As mentioned - it looks like you're using the wrong tool for the job. That to me looks like JSON. Which Regex is not the right thing to be doing

Comment: Consider to deserialize the string to a dictionary (via `JSONSerialization`)

Comment: I can't convert to JSON because I get the messages in the format of `{"code":5,"id":104,"message":"Not working"}{"code":5,"id":101,"message":"some message"}{"code":5,"id":105,"message":"test"}` sometimes. 

I'm already converting my String to JSON for the messages that come in correctly. I was thinking of using the regex in the cases where multiple strings come as one.

Comment: @Mark117 Just a pointer. Make a check against [msg length], if it is 0 your app will crash.

Comment: @Mark117 - can u show the code how do u get the `{"code":5,"id":104,"message":"Not working"}{"code":5,"id":101,"message":"some message"}{"code":5,"id":105,"message":"test"}`

Comment: I get the data from a Websocket connection. I reckon the device that is sending the data is broken, hence me trying to create a work around on iOS. I'm using the standard NSStreamDelegate code to manage

Comment: Note that } and { needs to be escaped in your case, because they have a meaning in Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  NSString *string = @"{\"code\":5,\"id\":104,\"message\":\"Not working\"}{\"code\":5,\"id\":101,\"message\":\"some message\"}{\"code\":5,\"id\":105,\"message\":\"test\"}";

  NSLog(@"String: %@", string);

  NSMutableArray *allSubDictAsStr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSString *pattern = @"\\{.*?\\}";
  NSError *errorRegex = nil;
  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&errorRegex];
  NSArray *results = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
  for (NSTextCheckingResult *aResult in results)
  {
    NSString *subJSONStr = [string substringWithRange:[aResult range]];
    [allSubDictAsStr addObject:subJSONStr];
  }
  NSString *bigJSONStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", [allSubDictAsStr componentsJoinedByString:@","]];

  NSError *errorJSON = nil;
  NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[bigJSONStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&errorJSON];
  NSLog(@"JsonArray: %@", jsonArray);
```

That's a possible solution, it's not really clean, but I got to play with Regex. Your issue could be more on your WebSocket parsing.

Idea : 
• Use a Regex to isolate each Dictionary JSON.
• Construct then an "array of dictionaries JSON" (`bigJSONStr`, as `NSString` in our case).

For the pattern, note that you have to escape `{` and `}` because they are reserved in Regular Expression.
I didn't check the `NSError` parameters, which is of course not recommended.

**EDIT:**
Additional note/modification: Rather than constructing "bigJSONStr" (which is quite ugly)

```
NSMutableArray *allResponses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
...
for (NSTextCheckingResult *aResult in results)
{
    NSString *subJSONStr = [string substringWithRange:[aResult range]];
    NSError *errorJSON = nil;
    NSDictionary *aResponseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[subJSONStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&errorJSON];
    if (!errorJSON) [allResponses addObject:subJSONStr];
}
NSLog(@"allResponses: %@", allResponses);
```

Comment: All I needed to do was escape the `{` and `}`. Thank you very much Larme

Answer (score 0):

do like

```
 //{"code":5,"id":104,"message":"Not working"}

// initially convert your JSON string to NSData
NSData *objectData = [JsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSError *error;
// deserialize using NSJSONSerialization
 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:0 error:&error];

// then serilize what ever your string
if (json)
{
NSString * code = json[@"code"];
NSString * ide = json[@"id"];
NSString * message = json[@"message"];
}
```

Comment: Do not post code-only answers. Provide some information what you have done and why that is so.

Comment: Upvoted. Keep it similiar in your other posts too please. Good work.

Comment: @Sneak - sure my bro

Comment: Thanks for the code but it's not relating to my problem. I updated the my description.

Comment: @Mark117 - the code is partially related to your question , if you add some additional code we will resolve

Comment: @Mark117 You are running a regex on your a JSON response as someone mentioned in the comments. You need to deserialize the JSON response, and run your REGEX through the actual **message** string from this solution.